# multiple generic type constraints with inheritance

Tags: c#, generics, types, constraints

I am trying to do the following with C#:

```
class SomeClass<T> : IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, T>>
```

obviously it doesn't work this way. Could you recommend a way to achieve this?

Sorry for not being precise. My point is that if I do something like this:

```
IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, T>> GetList() { 
    return new SomeClass<KeyValuePair<string,T>>();
}
```

I would need to explicitly cast to IEnumerable>, otherwise the compiler is giving the error "cannot implicitly convert type" Maybe it's something dumb/simple on my end.

Thanks,
Angel

Comment: What doesn't work?  You should be able to implement that interface just fine.

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work this way"? There are no type constraints here and there are no problems with implementing this interface.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the mistake is on my end, I need to do:

```
return new SomeClass<T>();
```

and the return type will actually be `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, T>>`

instead of :

```
return new SomeClass<KeyValuePair<string,T>>();
```

Since T is `KeyValuePair<string, T>>`.

Thanks guys and sorry for the confusion.

Angel